# Is there a hook for rules which I can use in my module to check if a specific rule has been fired?

Tags: 7, rules, hooks

I want to run some code to add php varible in js file just after my rule run. Rules doesn't support adding js.

I can make action to rule using [hook_rules_action_info](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21rules%21rules.api.php/function/hook_rules_action_info/7) but that does not work because adding js via rule action doesnt not work.

Is there a hook for rules which I can use in my module to check if a specific rule has been fired? and using that hook I can run my code just after rule run.

Thanks!

Comment: or is there any way by which I can check waht hook is used in action of my rule eg: on voting some node etc ?

Comment: you can already implement your own action

Comment: Implementing action is not useful as rules doesn't support adding js, I need to do drupal_add_js just after my rule fire so I need to mange this via my module code for which I need to know about which hook is used by rule or either hook used by rule action

Comment: I dont clearly understand what a problem here. If you can add your custom action in the specific position in rule - you can control its code start point. Another question is - how to detect that you adding js to specific page via rule?

Comment: No you are not getting my point as via rules we cannot add js see link: https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/anybody/2418721.                                         Add to add to particular ja file we can use drupal_add_js via module that's not a problem to add Php variable to particular js file

Comment: Any ideas how can I get information that which hook runs when particular rule fire ?

Comment: Mb this will help you, who knows
function hook_rules_config_execute($config){ dpm($config); }

Comment: Thanks but I think this hook runs before rule configuration loads is there any with help of which we can perform some code just after rule fire.....or I suppose with this I can check the hook used by rule  ?

Comment: Like ar7max, I'm having a hard time understanding why you can't just implement your own action, since the point of doing that is to run your module code. Regarding Rules and JS, I take it you've read [this thread](https://www.drupal.org/node/467024)?

Comment: Agree with @othermachines. Can you prvide to us (step-by-step) algorithm?

Comment: Thank you guys I will come up with more details I think I need to recheck with my custom action.

Comment: I used below method: 

http://cgit.drupalcode.org/sandbox-Anybody-2418721/tree/rules_js.rules.inc?id=19c885a

That will going to add java-script code etc or if set variable to all pages.

Is there any possibility that  I can set js variable into my module js file like below:


`drupal_add_js(array('custom_notify' => array('testvar' => "mytestvar")), array('type' => 'setting'));
     drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'custom_notify') . '/notify.js', 'file');`



Please suggest I am struggling to set js variable into my module js file just after my rule run.

Thanks!

Comment: Here Problem is I have to refresh page. When user vote on Node it is done without page refresh.

And rule got fired when user upvote or downvote at that time I need to set JS variable which I want to use in condition to run AJAX through JS file. 

Please suggest :)

Comment: Step by Step:

I have rules: when user up-vote, down-vote, comment, make revision etc and with these rule I store data in database table.

On instant actions like vote I fetch that data with ajax call which runs after each 20 sec which is deceasing performances. (to show data in block, just after any event)

So I want to set some JS variable just after my rule fire and then with help of that variable want to control ajax call.

After success of ajax just want to unset that variable and stop ajax, this way I will be able to avoid running ajax call every 20 sec. 

Please suggest